# href property refuses to be re-set after page load

Tags: javascript, properties, href

I have the following little snippet of code at the bottom of my page before the closing body tag:

```
var myAnchor = document.getElementById("tools").getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
var myHref = myAnchor.href;
myHref = "http://www.failblog.org";
alert(myHref);
```

The page alerts "http://www.failblog.org" as expected, but it doesn't actually change the value of the href attribute for the anchor.  The link stubbornly retains its original href.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did it the wrong way , try this:

```
   myHref = "http://www.failblog.org";
    var myAnchor = document.getElementById("tools").getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    myAnchor.href = myHref;
    alert(myHref);
```

Comment: Duh! I'm so dumb.  I was thinking that, because I'd previously given myHref the value myAnchor.href, when I gave myHref its new value I was saying myAnchor.href = "http://failblog.org" when actually I was giving myHref a new value and then doing nothing with it!  Thanks!

Comment: Those moments of "Duh!" happens a lot to any developer , it's ok :)

Answer (score 1):

When setting `var myHref = myAnchor.href;`, the string value of `myHref` will be set to the string value of `myAnchor.href;`, the variable isn't assigned as a reference, but as a copy of the value.

Answer (score 0):

Change the code to this:

```
var myHref = "http://www.failblog.org";
var myAnchor = document.getElementById("tools").getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
myAnchor.href = myHref;
```